# Set the height of an AlertDialog with a custom view of zero intrisic size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

### Context

A seamingly simple task, I want to set the height of an `AlertDialog` containing a custom view.  Going through the dozen of SO questions on this subject, I came up with 12! possible answers.  After having tried all of them (that's 15 years at a try per second), it seems that banging my head on the screen has the same effect: none.  The reason I want to do that is that my custom view has no intrisic dimensions, it just spans the space it is given.

---

### Goals

The question here refers to the soft goal, but I'd happily accept an answer for the hard goal!

**Soft goal:**  Create an `AlertDialog` having a custom empty `ViewGroup` (or containing, say, an `ImageView`), and set the dialog's width and height to a specific value.

**Hard goal:** Create an `AlertDialog` displaying a *square* shape taking the most space possible, when the dialog's dimensions are given programatically.

---

### My Tries, Condensed

**java:**

```
View layout = getLayoutInflater ().inflate (R.layout.alerttest, null);

AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder (this)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, null)
    .setTitle ("Don't cry, will you?")
    // .setView (layout) may be done here.
    .create();

alert.show ();

// alert.setView (layout) here, or before .show, or I can use the doc's:

FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) alert.findViewById (android.R.id.custom);
fl.addView (layout, new LayoutParams (500, 500)); // Arbitrary dimensions

alert.getWindow ().setLayout (800, 600);
// Or use before show (), or use alert.getWindow ().setAttributes with
// a WindowManager.LayoutParams crafted from getWindow ().getAttributes.
// Tried before and after show.
```

**alerttest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Tried with and without the encapsulating FrameLayout. -->
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="500dp"
                  android:layout_height="500dp">
        <!-- Tried with a Space, an ImageView with a src. -->
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Results:** When it does not crash (for usually good reasons), only the width is set.  Height is collapsed.

---

#### Related questions

- [Android:How can I set the AlertDialog width and height,and the button of the AlertDialog style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856550/androidhow-can-i-set-the-alertdialog-width-and-height-and-the-button-of-the-ale)
- [Height of an AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648477/height-of-a-alertdialog)
- [How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)

Thanks very much!